# How to get xml element using XML Predicate<XmlNode>?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlunit

I have the following lines

```
XmlNode controlNode = comparison.ControlDetails.Target;
XmlAttribute attr = controlNode as XmlAttribute; //I believe this line needs changing.
```

My goal is to get XML Node, [0] {Element, Name= “creationTimestamp”}, I’m not sure how to get this XML node and would appreciate some help, please let me know if you want more information, I’m just really stuck on this and have been for days, please help me get the above element, I've added my method to.

[debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5noJ.png)

Below is my ElementDifferenceEvaluatorTest.cs class with the xml and diff builder.

```
[TestFixture]
    public class ElementDifferenceEvaluatorTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestUserguideExample()
        {   string xmla = @"<sbl xmlns:fpml='www.test.co.uk'>
            <creationTimestamp>2018-09-12T17:33:06+01:00</creationTimestamp>
            <messageVersion>2.0</messageVersion>
            <publishedVersions>2.0</publishedVersions>
            <waqeBundle>
            <reference>123456</reference>
            <firstReference>1234567</firstReference>
            <version>15151515</version>
            <type>The-Buumi</type>
            <action>Yes</action>
            <subAction>new_sumie</subAction>
            </waqeBundle>
            <sourceEnvironment>UAT2</sourceEnvironment>
            </sbl>";

            string xmlb =
            @"<sbl xmlns:fpml='www.test.co.uk'>
            <messageVersion>2.0</messageVersion>
            <publishedVersions>2.0</publishedVersions>
            <waqeBundle>
            <reference>123456</reference>
            <firstReference>1234567</firstReference>
            <version>15151515</version>
            <type>The-Buumi</type>
            <action>Yes</action>
            <subAction>new_sumie</subAction>
            </waqeBundle>
            <sourceEnvironment>UAT2</sourceEnvironment>
            </sbl>";

            var myDiff = DiffBuilder.Compare(xmla).WithTest(xmlb)
                .WithDifferenceEvaluator(new ElementDifferenceEvaluator("creationTimestamp").Evaluate)
                .IgnoreComments()
                .CheckForSimilar()
                .Build();

            Assert.IsFalse(myDiff.HasDifferences(), myDiff.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Next is my ElementDifferenceEvaluator.cs

```
public class ElementDifferenceEvaluator
    {
        private string attributeName;

        public ElementDifferenceEvaluator(string attributeName)

        {
            this.attributeName = attributeName;

        }

        public ComparisonResult Evaluate(Comparison comparison, ComparisonResult outcome)

        {
            if (outcome == ComparisonResult.EQUAL || outcome == ComparisonResult.SIMILAR)
                return outcome; // only evaluate differences. 

            XmlNode controlNode = comparison.ControlDetails.Target; //why is this null?
            XmlAttribute attr = controlNode as XmlAttribute; //Why is this null?

            if (attr != null)

            {
                if (attr.Name == attributeName)
                {
                    return ComparisonResult.SIMILAR; // will evaluate this difference as similar 

                }
            }
            return outcome;
        } 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get the node `<creationTimeStamp/>`? If so-I would do it like this:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("your XML as a string");  //as an alternative, check out doc.Load()
XmlNodeList aNodes = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("creationTimeStamp");
```

This contains all tags by the Name creationTimeStamp, you could use `aNodes[0]` for the first item. Now, you have the possibility to look for attributes or other stuff, I mostly use `.InnerXml`

Comment: I have 2 string in another class string xmla and string xmlb

Comment: And you want to tell me what?

Comment: Still comes as null when I run the test

Comment: Could you provide the XML-file?

Comment: @shomsi did that

Comment: The problem is when i'm debugging the test method, the attr and control node have values, but when I'm not debugging it throws a null exception, I was wondering why they only have values when debugging and dont when just running test?

Comment: I get System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' at line     XmlNode attr = controlNode.SelectSingleNode("/sbl/creationTimestamp");

Comment: @Sam I think the problem is `"/sbl/creationTimestamp"`. I am actually working on something similar right now and I had this problem yesterday. I think it also didn't work when I selected a single node. I would recommend to use exactly my example, namely `XmlNodeList aNodes = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("creationTimestamp");` and see if the problem still occurs

Comment: could you edit my asnwer please? and add it to my above code

Comment: You need three lines of code, which are provided in my answer. Stackoverflow is there to help you and not to do your work entirely